# Inserting into a sorted array of structs in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, insertion-sort

I have to implement a vector using an array in C++ that is used to count the number of unique words from the input. It reads the input and then adds to the words to a struct which contains its count  and the unique word and then this is added to the vector. I have successfully implemented insert. The problem is that I can't get the inserting/ incrementing unique word count to work (elements aren't added to the vector). Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "MyVector.h"
using namespace std;

struct wordCount{
    string val;
    int count;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  enum { total, unique,individual } mode = total;
  for (int c; (c = getopt(argc, argv, "tui")) != EOF;) {
    switch(c) {
    case 't': mode = total; break;
    case 'u': mode = unique; break;
    case 'i': mode = individual; break;
    }
  }
  argc += optind;
  argv += optind;
  string word;
  Vector<wordCount> words;
  Vector<wordCount>::iterator it;
  int count = 0;
  while (cin >> word) {
    count++;
    if(mode == unique || mode == individual){
      for(it=words.begin();it != words.end();it++){
        if((it-1)->val <= word && it->val >= word){
            // Found word, increment its count
            if(it->val == word){
                it->count++;
                break;
            }
            // Otherwise insert the new unique word
            else{
              cout << "adding unique word" << endl;
              wordCount* wc;
              wc = new wordCount;
              wc->val = word;
              wc->count = 1;
              words.insert(it,*wc);
              break;
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  switch (mode) {
    case total: cout << "Total: " << count << endl; break;
    case unique: cout << "Unique: " << words.size() << endl; break;
    case individual:
        for(it=words.begin();it!=words.end();it++){
          cout << it->val << ": " << it->count << endl;}
        break;
  }
}
```

Comment: So if it's a duplicate word, what's the desired behavior? Should the duplicate be inserted?

Comment: if((it-1)->val <= word && it->val >= word), how is this checking supposed to work?

Comment: Duplicate words should increment the count of the word and not be inserted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say anything without seeing your implementation of
`Vector`.  If we assume it adheres to the standard container
conventions (and doesn't have an error in trying to do so): you
iterate starting with `it.begin(), but immediately access`
it-1`. That's undefined behavior for a standard container.  (I
don't know what it will do with your implementation of`Vector`,
but it would take some tricky code to make it work.)

At a higher level, there seems a basic inconsistency: you're
keeping the vector sorted, but still using linear search.  If
you're using linear search, there's no point in keeping the
vector sorted; just use:

```
Vector<wordCount>::iterator it = words.begin();
while ( it != words.end() && *it != word ) {
    ++ it;
}
if ( it == words.end() ) {
    //  not found, append to end...
} else {
    //  found, do whatever is appropriate...
}
```

(although I'd probably append to end, recover the iterator to
the newly inserted element, and treat it as if it were found).

Alternatively, if you're keeping the vector sorted, use a binary
search, not a linear search.

In either case, put the search in a separate function.  (If this
wasn't homework, I'd say just use `std::vector` and either
`std::find_if` or `std::lower_bound`.)

Also, why the `new` in the innermost `else`?  A more reasonable
approach would be to provide a constructor for `wordCount`
(which sets the count to 0), and do something like:

```
if ( ! found ) {
    it = words.insert( wordCount( word ) );
}
++ it->count;
```

The definition of `found` will depend on whether you're using
binary search or not.  In terms of the standard, this would be
either:

```
Vector<wordCount>::iterator it
    = std::find_if( words.begin(), words.end(), MatchWord( word );
if ( it == words.end() ) {
    it = words.insert( words.end(), wordCount( word ) );
}
++ it-count;
```

or

```
Vector<wordCount>::iterator it
    = std::lower_bound( words.begin(), words.end(), word, CompareWord() );
if ( it == words.end() || it->val != word ) {
    it = words.insert( wordCount( word ) );
++ it->count;
```

You should probably strive for something similar, with
a separate lookup function, returning either `end`, or the
position for the insertion when the value isn't found.

This keeps the various concerns clearly separated, and avoids
the excessive nesting in your code.  (You should probably try to
avoid `break` in general, and in multiply nested `if`s, it is
completely inacceptable—you'll notice that one of the
other people answering missed them, and misunderstood the
control flow because of it.)

Comment: I decided to go with a binary search which means inserting the wordCount so that it stays sorted. But I don't know how to insert and increment at the same time (so that only one loop is used which either ends up incrementing a count or inserting a new unique word).

Comment: If the entry isn't present, insert, and set the iterator to the inserted entry (the return value of `insert`).  Then increment through the iterator, exactly as if you'd found it.

Comment: I might add that this is a common idiom: look up and insert if not present.  You might want to look at `std::map<>::operator[]` for example.  (In your case, write a small function which returns an iterator to the corresponding entry, inserting it if necessary.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, why don't you use a `map`? That's exactly what it's for, mapping from one thing to another. From a `string` (the word) to an `int` (the number of occurences) in your case. Or do you have to use a vector?

Comment: This is homework. I suspect the whole *point* of the exercise is to implement a vector on top of a C array yourself.

Comment: @Frerich: Well, I personally have always been opposing to the idea of teaching (mostly) useless stuff that only takes time and can be done way easier another way.

Comment: I already did it with a map but the TA said it wasn't acceptable. I have to use an array.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a std::map.

```
Counter::Map words;
Counter count(words);

std::for_each(
    std::istream_iterator<std::string>(myInStream /*std::cin*/), 
    std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
    count);

std::copy(
    words.begin(),
    words.end(),
    std::ostream_iterator<Counter::Map::value_type>(myOutStream /*std::cout*/, "\n"));
```

The Counter functor could look like this

```
struct Counter
{
    typedef std::map<std::string, size_t> Map;
    Counter(Map& m) : words(&m) {}
    void operator()(const std::string& word)
    {
        Map::iterator it = words->lower_bound(word);
        if (it == words->end() || it->first != word)
            words->insert(it, std::make_pair(word, 1));
        else
            ++it->second; 
    }
    Map* words;
};
```

Using a std::vector

```
struct CounterVector
{
    typedef std::vector<std::pair<std::string, size_t> > Vector;
    CounterVector(Vector& m) : words(&m) {}

    struct WordEqual
    {
        const std::string* s;
        WordEqual(const std::string& w) : s(&w) {}
        bool operator()(Vector::const_reference p) const {
            return *s == p.first;}
    };

    void operator()(const std::string& word)
    {
        Vector::iterator it = std::find_if(
            words->begin(), words->end(), WordEqual(word));
        if (it == words->end())
            words->push_back(std::make_pair(word,1));
        else
            ++it->second;
    }
    Vector* words;
};
```

Comment: I already did that but the TA said it wasn't acceptable. I have to use an array.

Comment: You should avoid answering homework-questions with complete solutions. See [this topic on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).